# Why is my file output overwritten?

Tags: c, file, struct, formatting

My program takes user input and stores it in an array of Records that I've defined as a structure: `struct Record`.
The user input is are the fields of the struct. Everything complies error free, but it seems I can't get the formatting correct. My program keeps asking for user input until the user enters 'n' when asked if there are anymore records.
Once there are no more records the program loops through the created records and file prints each of them spaced out by tabs and at the end starting with a newline for the next record. However, instead of starting at a new line and printing another record in the same fashion, it overwrites the previous record printed and tabs the next one even further.
What causes this to happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Record
{
    char fname[51];
    char lname[51];
    char address[51];
    char city[51];
    char state[51];
    char zipcode[51];
    char phoneNumber[51];
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fileWriter;
    const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    char answer = 'y';
    int size = 1;
    int i = 0;
    struct Record *records;
    struct Record *records_temp = NULL;

    while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        struct Record *records_temp = calloc((size),sizeof(*records));         
        records = records_temp;
        printf("First Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].fname);

        printf("Last Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].lname);

        printf("Address: \n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", records[size-1].address);

        printf("City: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].city);

        printf("State: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].state);

        printf("Zipcode: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].zipcode);

        printf("Phone Number: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[size-1].phoneNumber);
        //stores all record info

        printf("Are there anymore records? [y/n] ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            size++;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
        //open file

    fileWriter = fopen(filename,"wb");

    if(fileWriter != NULL)
    {
        for(;i< size; i++)
        {
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records[i].fname);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records[i].lname);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records[i].address);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records[i].city);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records[i].state);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records[i].zipcode);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\n",records[i].phoneNumber);
        }
        free(records);
        fclose(fileWriter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening file.");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please strip down the problem to a minimal example. There is much code you can just remove. That makes others much more willing to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a little bit your code, but I think you should use linked list as a data structure here, it's more simple and consume less memory.
I made some tries and all went ok. :)
Hope that help you!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct Record Record;

struct Record
    {
        char fname[51];
        char lname[51];
        char address[51];
        char city[51];
        char state[51];
        char zipcode[51];
        char phoneNumber[51];

        Record *next;
    };


int main()
{
    FILE *fileWriter;
    const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    char answer = '\0';
    // int size = 1;
    // int i = 0;
    Record *records = NULL;
    Record *records_first = NULL;
    Record *records_previous = NULL;

    fileWriter = fopen(filename,"wb");

    if(fileWriter != NULL) {

        for( ; ; ) {
            records = (Record*) malloc(sizeof(Record));  

            if(records_first == NULL)
                records_first = records;

            if(records_previous != NULL)
                records_previous->next = records;

            records = records_first;
            printf("First Name: \n");
            scanf("%s", records->fname);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records->fname);

            printf("Last Name: \n");
            scanf("%s", records->lname);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records->lname);

            printf("Address: \n");
            scanf(" %[^\n]", records->address);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records->address);

            printf("City: \n");
            scanf("%s", records->city);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records->city);

            printf("State: \n");
            scanf("%s", records->state);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records->state);

            printf("Zipcode: \n");
            scanf("%s", records->zipcode);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t",records->zipcode);

            printf("Phone Number: \n");
            scanf("%s", records->phoneNumber);
            fprintf(fileWriter,"%s\t\n\n",records->phoneNumber);

            records->next = NULL;
            records_previous = records;

            printf("Are there anymore records? [y/n] ");
            scanf(" %c", &answer);

            if(tolower(answer) != 'y') {
                free(records);
                fclose(fileWriter);
                break;
            }
        }

    } else
        printf("Error opening file.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the typedef statement?

Comment: @Karlioh: As of now take that `typedef` is used for convenience of not having the need to write `struct Record` everywhere, instead you can simply write `Record`, for e.g `Record *next;` instead of `struct Record *next;`

Comment: The user input isn't being formatted right, the newline character doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with additional `a` mode as in "append". I think there is no need for further explanation what that would be good for, right?

However, the actual problem seems that you overwrite the pointer to the previous record already in the input loop. How is that supposed to work? Just go through that loop and try to follow the instructions as the program would do.

Problem is you cannot do it like this. Use a linked list for the allocated blocks.

Comment: Do you mean to use "wa" or "wba", or what exactly am I putting?

Comment: @Karlioh: what is unclear about "additional"? Do you understand what mode `b` means? If not, you should google or - better - get a good book.

Comment: So I've read up on file opening modes and realize I don't need the b for my text file, however when I added the a to "w" and made it "wa"  I get an error that says "Debug Assertion failed"

Comment: You did not read enough regarding the file modes. For a text file, you need the "t" actually - depending on OS, but better safe than sorry. Well, I already wrote many other errors. of your code. The actual problems are already int he input loop .. wait - didn't I write that already? Oh, yes. So please read.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
{
    struct Record *records_temp = calloc((size),sizeof(*records));

    records = records_temp;
    ...
}
```

Did you perhaps mean this?

```
while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
{
    struct Record *records_temp = realloc(records, size * sizeof *records);
    if (records_temp == NULL)
    {
         /* Handle allocation error */
    }
    records = records_temp;
    /* ... */
}
```

Do not confuse [`calloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/calloc.html) with [`realloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html). Read the manuals if you need further clarification.

**Don't forget to initialise `records` to `NULL`...**

---

If your concern is optimisation, the most significant bottleneck here will be your file input/output. That's unavoidable, and aside from researching [`setvbuf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) there isn't much you can do about it. The next bottleneck will be underlying calls to kernel allocation functions. You can reduce that bottleneck by calling allocation functions less. For example, you could grow your array by doubling its size each time rather than by adding 1:

```
size_t size = 0;
int answer;
do {
    size_t index = size++;
    if ((index & size) == 0) {
        void *temp = realloc(array, (2 * index + 1) * sizeof *array);
        if (temp == NULL) {
            /* Handle allocation error */
        }
        array = temp;
    }

    puts("First Name:");
    scanf("%s", array[index].fname);

    /* snip */

    answer = getchar();
} while (answer != EOF && tolower(answer) == 'y');
```

---

Alternatively, you could reinvent the wheel and perform the same work that `realloc` performs behind the scenes (and possibly lose some benefit of optimisation), by adding calls to `memcpy` and `free` to your code like so:

```
while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
{
    struct Record *records_temp = calloc((size),sizeof(*records));
    if (records_temp == NULL)
    {
        /* Handle allocation error */
    }
    if (records != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(records_temp, records, (size - 1) * sizeof *records);
        free(records);
    }
    records = records_temp;
    /* ... */
}
```

P.S. In case you missed it the first time: Don't forget to initialise `records` to `NULL`...

Comment: So that would be performing better than a linked list? copying all elements on each turn? Fragment memory? or even "reinvent the wheel". Great!

Comment: @Olaf This code is not *efficient*, but it can be made efficient quite easily... This answer introduces the bare minimum logic necessary to solve the problem. Yes. It's a better answer than introducing unnecessary logic, extra testcases and probably further problems.

Comment: There you are, @Olaf. I have introduced an efficient pattern. Please show me how the efficient pattern would 'fragment memory' more than your linked list suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem I see is memory allocation logic.  The first time through the loop, you allocate memory for 1 record and increment size.  The second time through the loop, you allocate memory for 2 more records, because size == 2.  The third time through the loop, you allocate memory for 3 more records, for a total of 1+2+3=6.

That answers why it's happening.  Olaf's suggested fix, linked list, is a good one.

Comment: Why is a linked list necessary to solve this problem?

Comment: @undefined behaviour Necessary is a strong word.  ;-)  Easy, simple, and useful fit better.  But a linked list is not necessary, strictly speaking.  With a size not known in advance, there must be a way to adapt as you go.  A linked list is one way, and realloc() sounds like another good way, too.

Comment: I struggle to see how introducing unnecessary logic is 'easy', 'simple' or 'useful'. To clarify: 'Why is a linked list necessary?' means 'Why do we need to be able to rearrange elements arbitrarily?' and 'Linked lists are unnecessary' means 'Linked lists are unsuitable here because there is no proof that we need to be able to rearrange elements arbitrarily. The additional logic is *unnecessary*.' If we were to all program like this, well... look how far it got GNOME.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: A linked list is one of the most basic, yet most versatile structure in programming (well - C-level programming). It is neither complicated nor is there need to "insert arbitrarily". It would be sufficient to have queue-operations put and get. What would be you simple, fast and compact suggestion? Criticizing is easy, unless you have to come up with a better idea. Your turn!

Comment: I agree with @Olaf here. Linked list looks like a probable solution to this problem than the dynamic memory allocation with `realloc()`. That said, complexity in implementation of Linked List depends on the developer who is writing the code. For beginners who are making logical errors in simple loops, Linked List is a long way to go.

Comment: @Olaf An efficient implementation of linked lists will require at least as much code as an efficient implementation of a growing array... and typically between four and eight bytes extra memory per element. **This code here can be adapted so that it works correctly in four lines of code** (see my post). The question I'm raising is: Is the extra memory (in the form of pointers to 'next' nodes), and the logic that corresponds to it *necessary*?